# appending new row in table is distorted jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
var data = [{
    "landpin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landarp": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "landfirstname": "John",
        "landmiddlename": "James",
        "landlastname": "Jones",
        "landsuffix": "",
        "landqtr": "1st",
        "landyear": "2014",
        "landkindcode": "1",
        "landkindname": "Land",
        "landkindsysid": "1",
        "landsurvey": "PSD-413-621-513",
        "landtct_cloa": "OCT-351-561-623",
        "landarea": "1000",
        "landclassification": "Residential",
        "landclasscode": "R",
        "landprovince": "Province",
        "landmunicipality": "Municipality",
        "landbarangay": "District",
        "landlot": "3",
        "landblock": "6",
        "LandAddress": [{
        "landownercontactflag": "0",
            "landownerprovince": "Province",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "landownerstreet": "23",
            "landownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "landownercontactflag": "1",
            "landownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "landownerstreet": "34",
            "landownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "bldgpin": "015-08-0011-000-01-1001",
        "bldgtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "bldgfirstname": "John",
        "bldgmiddlename": "James",
        "bldglastname": "Jones",
        "bldgsuffix": "",
        "bldgqtr": "1st",
        "bldgyear": "2013",
        "bldgkindcode": "10",
        "bldgkindname": "Buildings and Other Structures",
        "bldgkindsysid": "10",
        "BuildingAddress": [{
        "bldgownercontactflag": "0",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "bldgownerstreet": "23",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "bldgownercontactflag": "1",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "bldgownerstreet": "34",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "mchnspin": "015-08-0011-000-01-2001",
        "mchnstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "mchnsfirstname": "John",
        "mchnsmiddlename": "James",
        "mchnslastname": "Jones",
        "mchnssuffix": "",
        "mchnsqtr": "1st",
        "mchnsyear": "2013",
        "mchnskindcode": "3",
        "mchnskindname": "Machinery",
        "mchnskindsysid": "3",
        "otherspin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "otherstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "otherfirstname": "John",
        "othermiddlename": "James",
        "otherlastname": "Jones",
        "othersuffix": "",
        "othersqtr": "1st",
        "othersyear": "2013",
        "otherskindcode": "11",
        "otherskindname": "Other Improvements",
        "otherskindsysid": "11"
}, {
    "landpin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landarp": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "landfirstname": "John",
        "landmiddlename": "James",
        "landlastname": "Jones",
        "landsuffix": "",
        "landqtr": "1st",
        "landyear": "2014",
        "landkindcode": "1",
        "landkindname": "Land",
        "landkindsysid": "1",
        "landsurvey": "PSD-413-621-513",
        "landtct_cloa": "OCT-351-561-623",
        "landarea": "1000",
        "landclassification": "Residential",
        "landclasscode": "R",
        "landprovince": "Province",
        "landmunicipality": "Municipality",
        "landbarangay": "District",
        "landlot": "3",
        "landblock": "6",
        "LandAddress": [{
        "landownercontactflag": "0",
            "landownerprovince": "Province",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "landownerstreet": "23",
            "landownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "landownercontactflag": "1",
            "landownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "landownerstreet": "34",
            "landownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "bldgpin": "015-08-0011-000-01-1001",
        "bldgtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "bldgfirstname": "John",
        "bldgmiddlename": "James",
        "bldglastname": "Jones",
        "bldgsuffix": "",
        "bldgqtr": "1st",
        "bldgyear": "2014",
        "bldgkindcode": "10",
        "bldgkindname": "Buildings and Other Structures",
        "bldgkindsysid": "10",
        "BuildingAddress": [{
        "bldgownercontactflag": "0",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "bldgownerstreet": "23",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "bldgownercontactflag": "1",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "bldgownerstreet": "34",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "mchnspin": "015-08-0011-000-01-2001",
        "mchnstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "mchnsfirstname": "John",
        "mchnsmiddlename": "James",
        "mchnslastname": "Jones",
        "mchnssuffix": "",
        "mchnsqtr": "1st",
        "mchnsyear": "2013",
        "mchnskindcode": "3",
        "mchnskindname": "Machinery",
        "mchnskindsysid": "3",
        "otherspin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "otherstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "otherfirstname": "John",
        "othermiddlename": "James",
        "otherlastname": "Jones",
        "othersuffix": "",
        "othersqtr": "1st",
        "othersyear": "2013",
        "otherskindcode": "11",
        "otherskindname": "Other Improvements",
        "otherskindsysid": "11"
}]
var arr2 = [];
var landtr = $('<tr><tr/>');
var bldgtr = $('<tr><tr/>');
var td;
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  td = $('<td/>');
  var land = data[i].landpin + data[i].landyear + data[i].landkindsysid;
  var bldg = data[i].bldgpin + data[i].bldgyear + data[i].bldkindsysid;
  var mchns = data[i].mchnspin + data[i].mchnsyear + data[i].mchnskindsysid;
  var others = data[i].otherspin + data[i].othersyear + data[i].otherskindsysid;
  if ($.inArray(land, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
    arr2.push(land);

    if (data[i].landpin) {
      var landaddress = data[i].LandAddress;

      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landpin + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + (data[i].landlot ? "Lot " + data[i].landlot : "") + "/" + (data[i].landblock ? "Block " + data[i].landblock : "") + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landfirstname + " " + data[i].landmiddlename + " " + data[i].landlastname + ", " + data[i].landsuffix + "</td>");
      for (var land = 0; land < landaddress.length; land++) {
        var contactaddress;
        var homeaddress;
        landtr.append("<td id=''>" + landaddress[land].landownercontactflag === "1" ? (contactaddress = landaddress[land].landownerprovince + " " + landaddress[land].landownermunicipality + " " + landaddress[land].landownerbarangay + ", " + landaddress[land].landownerstreet) : (homeaddress = landaddress[land].landownerprovince + " " + landaddress[land].landownermunicipality + " " + landaddress[land].landownerbarangay + ", " + landaddress[land].landownerstreet) + "</td>");
      }
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landkindname + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landclassification + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landfinalvalue + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''></td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landyear + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''></td>");

    }
    $("#searchresult").append(landtr);
  }
  if ($.inArray(bldg, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
    arr2.push(bldg);
    if (data[i].bldgpin) {
      var bldgaddress = data[i].BuildingAddress;

      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgarp + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgarp + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgpin + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + (data[i].bldglot ? "Lot " + data[i].bldglot : "") + "/" + (data[i].bldgblock ? "Block " + data[i].bldgblock : "") + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgfirstname + " " + data[i].bldgmiddlename + " " + data[i].bldglastname + ", " + data[i].bldgsuffix + "</td>");
      for (var bldg = 0; bldg < bldgaddress.length; bldg++) {
        var contactaddress;
        var homeaddress;
        bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownercontactflag === "1" ? (contactaddress = bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerprovince + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownermunicipality + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerbarangay + ", " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerstreet) : (homeaddress = bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerprovince + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownermunicipality + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerbarangay + ", " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerstreet) + "</td>");
      }
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgkindname + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgclassification + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgfinalvalue + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''></td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgyear + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    }
    $("#searchresult").append(bldgtr);
  }
  //                if ($.inArray(mchns, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
  //                        arr2.push(mchns);
  //                    if(data[i].mchnspin){
  //                        $("#searchresult").append("<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].mchnspin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnstin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td data-table='machines'>" + data[i].mchnskindname + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsfirstname + " " + data[i].mchnsmiddlename + " " + data[i].mchnslastname + ", " + data[i].mchnssuffix + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsqtr + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsyear + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].mchnspin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td></tr>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnstin + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsfirstname + " " + data[i].mchnsmiddlename + " " + data[i].mchnslastname + ", " + data[i].mchnssuffix + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsqtr + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsyear + "</td>");
  //                    }
  //                }
  //                if ($.inArray(others, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
  //                        arr2.push(others);
  //                    if(data[i].otherspin){
  //                        $("#searchresult").append("<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].otherspin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].otherstin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td data-table='otherimprov'>" + data[i].otherskindname + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].otherfirstname + " " + data[i].othermiddlename + " " + data[i].otherlastname + ", " + data[i].othersuffix + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].othersqtr + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].othersyear + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].otherspin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td></tr>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].otherstin + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].othersfirstname + " " + data[i].othersmiddlename + " " + data[i].otherslastname + ", " + data[i].otherssuffix + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].othersqtr + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].othersyear + "</td>");
  //                    }
  //                }
  //tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].reg_year + "</td>");
  //tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].pin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td>");
  //$("#searchresult").append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="searchresult">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>ARPN</td>
    <td>T.D.
      <br>NO.</td>
    <td>PIN</td>
    <td>LOT/
      <br>BLOCK
      <br>NO.</td>
    <td>PROPERTY
      <br>OWNER</td>
    <td>ADDRESS OF
      <br>PROPERTY
      <br>OWNER</td>
    <td>K
      <br>I
      <br>N
      <br>D</td>
    <td>CLASSIFI-
      <br>CATION</td>
    <td>ASSESSED
      <br>VALUE</td>
    <td>LEGAL
      <br>BASIS</td>
    <td>EFFECTIVITY</td>
    <td>REMARKS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to append new row in table depending on the the pin. I am appending 4 types in my example i only added 2. When adding land the table is ok when i added building the table becomes distorted. It does not add new row instead it continues to previous row i specifically put var with value `$('<tr><tr/>')` and I append the data in that variable like `variable.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].value+ "</td>")` but then why is it that the table is distorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see two errors in your code:

- You were declaring the `landtr` and `ldgtr` outside the loop, and then you were creating only one row and appending all the `td` tags inside those same two rows.
- Your address code was with some shorthand statements (e.g `true ? x : y`) that you were not using parenthesis to delimit them, that was causing some logic errors.

Take a look at your modified code below with the two errors above fixed:

```js
var data = [{
    "landpin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landarp": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "landfirstname": "John",
        "landmiddlename": "James",
        "landlastname": "Jones",
        "landsuffix": "",
        "landqtr": "1st",
        "landyear": "2014",
        "landkindcode": "1",
        "landkindname": "Land",
        "landkindsysid": "1",
        "landsurvey": "PSD-413-621-513",
        "landtct_cloa": "OCT-351-561-623",
        "landarea": "1000",
        "landclassification": "Residential",
        "landclasscode": "R",
        "landprovince": "Province",
        "landmunicipality": "Municipality",
        "landbarangay": "District",
        "landlot": "3",
        "landblock": "6",
        "LandAddress": [{
        "landownercontactflag": "0",
            "landownerprovince": "Province",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "landownerstreet": "23",
            "landownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "landownercontactflag": "1",
            "landownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "landownerstreet": "34",
            "landownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "bldgpin": "015-08-0011-000-01-1001",
        "bldgtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "bldgfirstname": "John",
        "bldgmiddlename": "James",
        "bldglastname": "Jones",
        "bldgsuffix": "",
        "bldgqtr": "1st",
        "bldgyear": "2013",
        "bldgkindcode": "10",
        "bldgkindname": "Buildings and Other Structures",
        "bldgkindsysid": "10",
        "BuildingAddress": [{
        "bldgownercontactflag": "0",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "bldgownerstreet": "23",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "bldgownercontactflag": "1",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "bldgownerstreet": "34",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "mchnspin": "015-08-0011-000-01-2001",
        "mchnstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "mchnsfirstname": "John",
        "mchnsmiddlename": "James",
        "mchnslastname": "Jones",
        "mchnssuffix": "",
        "mchnsqtr": "1st",
        "mchnsyear": "2013",
        "mchnskindcode": "3",
        "mchnskindname": "Machinery",
        "mchnskindsysid": "3",
        "otherspin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "otherstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "otherfirstname": "John",
        "othermiddlename": "James",
        "otherlastname": "Jones",
        "othersuffix": "",
        "othersqtr": "1st",
        "othersyear": "2013",
        "otherskindcode": "11",
        "otherskindname": "Other Improvements",
        "otherskindsysid": "11"
}, {
    "landpin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landarp": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "landtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "landfirstname": "John",
        "landmiddlename": "James",
        "landlastname": "Jones",
        "landsuffix": "",
        "landqtr": "1st",
        "landyear": "2014",
        "landkindcode": "1",
        "landkindname": "Land",
        "landkindsysid": "1",
        "landsurvey": "PSD-413-621-513",
        "landtct_cloa": "OCT-351-561-623",
        "landarea": "1000",
        "landclassification": "Residential",
        "landclasscode": "R",
        "landprovince": "Province",
        "landmunicipality": "Municipality",
        "landbarangay": "District",
        "landlot": "3",
        "landblock": "6",
        "LandAddress": [{
        "landownercontactflag": "0",
            "landownerprovince": "Province",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "landownerstreet": "23",
            "landownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "landownercontactflag": "1",
            "landownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "landownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "landownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "landownerstreet": "34",
            "landownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "bldgpin": "015-08-0011-000-01-1001",
        "bldgtin": "342-432-423-000",
        "bldgfirstname": "John",
        "bldgmiddlename": "James",
        "bldglastname": "Jones",
        "bldgsuffix": "",
        "bldgqtr": "1st",
        "bldgyear": "2014",
        "bldgkindcode": "10",
        "bldgkindname": "Buildings and Other Structures",
        "bldgkindsysid": "10",
        "BuildingAddress": [{
        "bldgownercontactflag": "0",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 2",
            "bldgownerstreet": "23",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "4311"
    }, {
        "bldgownercontactflag": "1",
            "bldgownerprovince": "Province 2",
            "bldgownermunicipality": "Municipality 3",
            "bldgownerbarangay": "District 3",
            "bldgownerstreet": "34",
            "bldgownerzipcode": "1218"
    }],
        "mchnspin": "015-08-0011-000-01-2001",
        "mchnstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "mchnsfirstname": "John",
        "mchnsmiddlename": "James",
        "mchnslastname": "Jones",
        "mchnssuffix": "",
        "mchnsqtr": "1st",
        "mchnsyear": "2013",
        "mchnskindcode": "3",
        "mchnskindname": "Machinery",
        "mchnskindsysid": "3",
        "otherspin": "015-08-0011-000-01",
        "otherstin": "342-432-423-000",
        "otherfirstname": "John",
        "othermiddlename": "James",
        "otherlastname": "Jones",
        "othersuffix": "",
        "othersqtr": "1st",
        "othersyear": "2013",
        "otherskindcode": "11",
        "otherskindname": "Other Improvements",
        "otherskindsysid": "11"
}]
var arr2 = [];
var td;
var tr;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  
var landtr = $('<tr><tr/>');
var bldgtr = $('<tr><tr/>');
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  td = $('<td/>');
  var land = data[i].landpin + data[i].landyear + data[i].landkindsysid;
  var bldg = data[i].bldgpin + data[i].bldgyear + data[i].bldkindsysid;
  var mchns = data[i].mchnspin + data[i].mchnsyear + data[i].mchnskindsysid;
  var others = data[i].otherspin + data[i].othersyear + data[i].otherskindsysid;
  if ($.inArray(land, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
    arr2.push(land);

    if (data[i].landpin) {
      var landaddress = data[i].LandAddress;

      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landarp + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landpin + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + (data[i].landlot ? "Lot " + data[i].landlot : "") + "/" + (data[i].landblock ? "Block " + data[i].landblock : "") + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landfirstname + " " + data[i].landmiddlename + " " + data[i].landlastname + ", " + data[i].landsuffix + "</td>");
      var td_content = [];
      for (var land = 0; land < landaddress.length; land++) {
        var contactaddress;
        var homeaddress;
        td_content.push((landaddress[land].landownercontactflag === "1" ? (contactaddress = landaddress[land].landownerprovince + " " + landaddress[land].landownermunicipality + " " + landaddress[land].landownerbarangay + ", " + landaddress[land].landownerstreet) : (homeaddress = landaddress[land].landownerprovince + " " + landaddress[land].landownermunicipality + " " + landaddress[land].landownerbarangay + ", " + landaddress[land].landownerstreet)));
      }
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + td_content.join(' / ') + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landkindname + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landclassification + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landfinalvalue + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''></td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].landyear + "</td>");
      landtr.append("<td id=''></td>");

    }
    $("#searchresult").append(landtr);
  }
  if ($.inArray(bldg, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
    arr2.push(bldg);
    if (data[i].bldgpin) {
      var bldgaddress = data[i].BuildingAddress;

      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgarp + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgarp + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgpin + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + (data[i].bldglot ? "Lot " + data[i].bldglot : "") + "/" + (data[i].bldgblock ? "Block " + data[i].bldgblock : "") + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgfirstname + " " + data[i].bldgmiddlename + " " + data[i].bldglastname + ", " + data[i].bldgsuffix + "</td>");
      var td_content = [];
      for (var bldg = 0; bldg < bldgaddress.length; bldg++) {
        var contactaddress;
        var homeaddress;
        td_content.push((bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownercontactflag === "1" ? (contactaddress = bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerprovince + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownermunicipality + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerbarangay + ", " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerstreet) : (homeaddress = bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerprovince + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownermunicipality + " " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerbarangay + ", " + bldgaddress[bldg].bldgownerstreet)));
      }
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + td_content.join(' / ') + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgkindname + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgclassification + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgfinalvalue + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''></td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].bldgyear + "</td>");
      bldgtr.append("<td id=''></td>");
    }
    $("#searchresult").append(bldgtr);
  }
  //                if ($.inArray(mchns, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
  //                        arr2.push(mchns);
  //                    if(data[i].mchnspin){
  //                        $("#searchresult").append("<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].mchnspin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnstin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td data-table='machines'>" + data[i].mchnskindname + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsfirstname + " " + data[i].mchnsmiddlename + " " + data[i].mchnslastname + ", " + data[i].mchnssuffix + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsqtr + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsyear + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].mchnspin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td></tr>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnstin + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsfirstname + " " + data[i].mchnsmiddlename + " " + data[i].mchnslastname + ", " + data[i].mchnssuffix + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsqtr + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].mchnsyear + "</td>");
  //                    }
  //                }
  //                if ($.inArray(others, arr2) == -1) { //check if id value not exits than add it
  //                        arr2.push(others);
  //                    if(data[i].otherspin){
  //                        $("#searchresult").append("<tr><td id=''>" + data[i].otherspin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].otherstin + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td data-table='otherimprov'>" + data[i].otherskindname + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].otherfirstname + " " + data[i].othermiddlename + " " + data[i].otherlastname + ", " + data[i].othersuffix + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].othersqtr + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + data[i].othersyear + "</td>"
  //                                +"<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].otherspin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td></tr>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].otherstin + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].othersfirstname + " " + data[i].othersmiddlename + " " + data[i].otherslastname + ", " + data[i].otherssuffix + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].othersqtr + "</td>");
  //                        tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].othersyear + "</td>");
  //                    }
  //                }
  //tr.append("<td id=''>" + data[i].reg_year + "</td>");
  //tr.append("<td id=''>" + "<a class=\"af_rpta_treasuryall_specificpin\"  id=" + data[i].pin + " href='#' >View Details</a>" + "</td>");
  //$("#searchresult").append(tr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" id="searchresult">
  <tr align="center">
    <td>ARPN</td>
    <td>T.D.
      <br>NO.</td>
    <td>PIN</td>
    <td>LOT/
      <br>BLOCK
      <br>NO.</td>
    <td>PROPERTY
      <br>OWNER</td>
    <td>ADDRESS OF
      <br>PROPERTY
      <br>OWNER</td>
    <td>K
      <br>I
      <br>N
      <br>D</td>
    <td>CLASSIFI-
      <br>CATION</td>
    <td>ASSESSED
      <br>VALUE</td>
    <td>LEGAL
      <br>BASIS</td>
    <td>EFFECTIVITY</td>
    <td>REMARKS</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to display all the addresses in one single `td`, you must create an auxiliar variable to concatenate all the addresses, and then append the concatenation into a single `td`.

Look at the updated example above.

Comment: There is one thing you need to clarify with one though please combine the address in one td now they are separated in two td. I need them in one td separated by `/`

Comment: happy coding i still new at using short hand statement so i didnt saw that there was error there because the console didnt show it

Comment: I have one more question i tried solving it on my own but i have been going in circle for hours. Why do i get duplicate row?please enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

You need to clone your `tr` variables, otherwise you'll keep appending to the same `tr` element. For a start change your variables here to:

```
var land_tr = $('<tr><tr/>');
var bldg_tr = $('<tr><tr/>');
```

Then, add a clone line as shown below:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var landtr = land_tr.clone(); // <<<<--- ADD THIS
  var bldgtr = bldg_tr.clone(); // <<<<--- ADD THIS
  tr = $('<tr/>');
  td = $('<td/>');
  var land = data[i].landpin + data[i].landyear + data[i].landkindsysid;
```

**Please note:** Even though your browser does not complain, the proper element to append a `tr` element to is a `tbody`, `thead` or `tfoot` element.

Comment: Im getting `land_tr` undefined. I dont understand why i need to clone them

Comment: That's because you probably did not make the first change suggested. You're cloning so that at the start of every loop you have a fresh row. And the original is still intact.